# Where does Tomcat log JNDI failures for data sources?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I recently tracked down a problem using a JNDI data source with my tomcat project, and found I was using an incorrect type.  context.xml included the following:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/myDataSource" type="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" ...
```

when it should have used:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/myDataSource" type="javax.sql.DataSource" ...
```

I wasted 5 hours on this simple issue because I saw no useful error messages related to the problem.  I'm referencing the resource in Spring with:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/myDataSource" />
```

..and the only feedback I received was

```
SEVERE: Servlet /myServlet threw load() exception
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:146)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    ...
```

I'm really curious about best way to debug this type of problem.  I've created an empty Tomcat instance with this resource declared in context.xml, but no errors are logged, and /manager/text/resources doesn't seem to show either the correct or incorrect version of myDataSource.

Comment: The resource isn't created until used.

Comment: Thanks.  That explains why I couldn't reproduce it with an empty instance.  But even when Spring was attempting (and failing) to load the resource, the logs gave no clues as to the root cause.